# find the index of array of object and replace it with object

Tags: arrays, angular, object

here is my .ts file

```
export class CustomerFormDataComponent implements OnInit {
id: number = 0;
custName!: string;
custEmail!: string;
@ViewChild(CustomerAddressDataComponent, { static: true })
child!: CustomerAddressDataComponent;
selectedStatusValue!: string;
@ViewChild('f') customerDetailForm!: NgForm;
customerData: customerListInterface[] = [];
selectedCustomerId!: number;
constructor(public userDataservice: UserDataService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.customerData = this.userDataservice.userData;
  // default value for status dropdown
  this.selectedStatusValue = 'Active';
  // edit data functionality
  this.userDataservice.editData.subscribe((user) => {
    // i get here {id: 2, name:'heli', email: 'heli @gmail.com', address:'rajokt',status: 'active'}
    //global veriable for stroring id of object
    this.selectedCustomerId = user.id;
    this.id = user.id;
    this.custName = user.name;
    this.custEmail = user.email;
    this.child.addressData = user.address;
    this.selectedStatusValue = user.status;
  });
}

selectedDropDownValue(event: any) {
  this.selectedStatusValue = event.target.value;
}

// onclick on submit
onclickSubmit() {
  
  let data = this.customerData.forEach((o) => o.id);
  console.log(this.selectedCustomerId && data);
  if (this.selectedCustomerId === this.customerData[0].id) {
    this.customerData.splice(this.selectedCustomerId, 1, {
      id: this.id,
      name: this.custName,
      email: this.custEmail,
      address: this.child.addressData,
      status: this.selectedStatusValue,
    });
  } else {
    this.customerData.push({
      id: this.id++,
      name: this.custName,
      email: this.custEmail,
      address: this.child.addressData,
      status: this.selectedStatusValue,
    });
  }

  this.customerDetailForm.reset();
  this.child.addressData = '';
}
}
```

on click i want to compare array of obejct with object if id is same then i should be removed with another object if data is not same then it should push to the array as new data

i have tried to find the id of object but could not my array is like below

customerData = [{id:1, name:'heli',email:'heli@gmail.com' address:'rajkot',status:'active'},{id:2, name:'janvi',email:'janvi@gmail.com' address:'rajkot',status:'active'}]

object is like below

user = {id:1, name:'suhana',email:'suhana@gmail.com' address:'rajkot',status:'active'}

so i want to replace user  object with array of object if id is same if id is not same then push it to array othervise replace it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **findIndex()** method of the array to get the index of the object with the same ID as the user object. If an object with the same ID is found, you can replace it with the user object using the index. If an object with the same ID is not found, you can push the user object to the customerData array. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
// onclick on submit
onclickSubmit() {
  const user = {
    id: this.id,
    name: this.custName,
    email: this.custEmail,
    address: this.child.addressData,
    status: this.selectedStatusValue,
  };

  const index = this.customerData.findIndex((o) => o.id === user.id);

  if (index !== -1) {
    this.customerData.splice(index, 1, user);
  } else {
    this.customerData.push(user);
  }

  this.customerDetailForm.reset();
  this.child.addressData = '';
}
```

Hope it's helpful..!

Comment: yeah i did some changes and it worked thanks